# Opening a plink window from VB.NET application without showing the black ugly plink window

Tags: vb.net, putty, plink

I am looking to call plink from a vb.net application in the background (without showing the black plink cmd screen) is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.  See the instructions on [dreamincode.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/185278-interact-with-command-line-process-in-vbnet/page__view__findpost__p__1086807?s=48b4fbeee3b201e6bfc9189d3254d280).

Basically, you want to hide the window, and redirect standard in/out.

```
Dim p as New Process
With p.StartInfo
    .WindowStyle=ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    .RedirectStandardOutput=true
    .RedirectStandardInput=true
End With
```

You can then read and write using [`p.StandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) and [`p.StandardOutput][3]`.

You can find more options to set as well in the [ProcessStartInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx).