# Feed From CMD VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, cmd

I am writing a utility for Minecraft Coder pack. It works off batch files that run python. Is it possible to read and write from the cmd into say a text box and run commands for vb.net to the cmd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  See my answer here:  [Opening a plink window from VB.NET application without showing the black ugly plink window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760236/opening-a-plink-window-from-vb-net-application-without-showing-the-black-ugly-pli/6763935#6763935)

Basically, you want to hide the window, and redirect standard in/out.

```
Dim p as New Process
With p.StartInfo
    .WindowStyle=ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    .RedirectStandardOutput=true
    .RedirectStandardInput=true
End With
```

You can then read and write using [`p.StandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) and [`p.StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx).

You can find more options to set as well in the [ProcessStartInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx).