# C# Http Server with PHP

Tags: c#, php, http

I'm currently writing an http server in C# and I'm planning on allowing it to use PHP. How does PHP work? Like, the compiler or whatever it uses. I was thinking it takes php files in input and outputs the html or whatever file for the http server to give to the user's request. Is it possible to call on the php compiler or whatever with the file requested by the user? Please tell me if I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: Do not do this. Please.

Comment: @Andrew, you're right.  He should use it to interact with COBOL.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to interact with PHP.  The easiest way to get started is to implement CGI in your program.

[Wikipedia has a nice example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Simple_Example).

Basically, you execute PHP-CGI.exe, and [send/receive data over standard in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760236/opening-a-plink-window-from-vb-net-application-without-showing-the-black-ugly-pli/6763935#6763935).